# In Kotlin, Can I add an Elvis expression to a simpledateformat format?

Tags: android, kotlin

In Kotlin, Can I add an Elvis expression to a simpledateformat format?  The compiler seems to accept it, but not sure of the results.  Perhaps there is a better way to express this?

```
sdf.format(getDateFromDatebase(nullibleDate))?:""
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Why are you passing a date to getDateFromDatebase? What does this function return?

Comment: getDateFromDatabase inputs a nullable date and returns a nullable date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## How to work with nullable types

If you use ?. you can invoke methods only if the left side is not null, so you could rewrite your code as:

```
nullibleDate
    ?.let { getDateFromDatebase(it) } 
    ?.let { sdf.format(it) } ?:""
```

This uses let, which passes the value it is called on to the block, inside the block it can be refered to as it.

If any stage of this returns null it will be passed through to the end, where the elvis operator `?:` will replace null with an empty string.

Comment: Does 'it' always refer to the first variable on the chain?

Comment: It refers to the thing that let is called on, so in the first block it is nullibleDate, in the second it is the result of getDateFromDatebase

Comment: Kotlin is amazing :-)

Comment: If you need to repeat this you might want to look at extension functions